# How to get small_image in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, small-image

I am trying to get URL of small_image.

Magento 2 offers a helper `helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')`.

I used this code to load `small_image`

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'small_image')
        ->setImageFile($block->getProductForThumbnail()->getImage())
        ->resize(165, 165)->getUrl(); ?>
```

But this code throws me this error.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image::loadImageInfoFromCache() must be of the type string, null given, called in /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 612 and defined in /Users/suman/the-webster/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 892
```

[image]

How to get `small_image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So remembering in m2 you can set image dimensions in xml

app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml file.

```xml
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
```

You can use below code.

```php
//$image = 'category_page_grid' or 'category_page_list';
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->resize(165)->getUrl();
```

```html
    <img src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" />
```